# Entailment of two formulae

Tags: logic

If I have two statement, say $A$ and $B$. From which, I formed two formulae:

$F_1$: ~$A$ $\&$ ~$B$

$F_2$: ~$A$ $\mid$ ~$B$

Do $F_1$ and $F_2$ *entail* each other?

Comment: If $|$ is the [Sheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke), than $\lnot A \mid \lnot B$ is simply : $A \land B$. Thus : $F_2 \nvDash F_1$, because otherwise $A \land B \vDash \lnot A \land \lnot B$, which is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your $|$ is meant for 'or' (in programming it often is), and an *inclusive* or at that (again, in programming it often is used as such).

So, using more 'standard' logical symbols, the statements are:

$F_1: \neg A \land \neg B$

$F_2: \neg A \lor \neg B$

Now, a statement $\phi$ *entails* a statement $\psi$ if and only if $\psi$ has to be true if we assume $\phi$ is true.

So in this case:

$F_1$ entails $F_2$, because if we assume that $F_1$ is true, then $\neg A \land \neg B$ is true, hence in particular $\neg A$, and that means that $\neg A \lor \neg B$ is true (think about it: if $P$ is true, then of course $P \lor Q$ will be true as well)

On the other hand, $F_2$ does not entail $F_1$, since we could have a situation where $A$ is true, and $B$ is false: that would mean that $\neg B$ is true, and hence $\neg A \lor \neg B$ (i.e. $F_2$) is true, but since $A$ is true, clearly $\neg A \land \neg B$ (i.e. $F_1$) is false. So this shows that it is possible for $F_2$ to be true but $F_1$ to be false, so $F_2$ does not entail $F_1$.

Comment: Very informative. I had the second confusion. Thank you sir.